# Can't Open Binary Stream of file on Sharepoint Documents

Tags: sharepoint-addin

I am trying to read stream from a file on Sharepoint Document library. My app has full control on documents.

OpenBinaryStream throws exception 403. The code works if I use SharePoint Credentials by providing username and password but I want to do this using oauth

I am using following method to access file.

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File file = GetTheFileFromTheDocLibrary("expViewSt.xlsx");
            SharePointContextToken contextToken;
            string accessToken;
            Uri sharepointUrl = new Uri(Session["SPHostUrl"].ToString());
            TokenHelper.TrustAllCertificates();
            string contextTokenString = Session["contextToken"].ToString();
            contextToken =
                TokenHelper.ReadAndValidateContextToken(contextTokenString, Request.Url.Authority);
            accessToken =
                TokenHelper.GetAccessToken(contextToken, sharepointUrl.Authority).AccessToken;                 
            ClientContext clientContext = TokenHelper.GetClientContextWithAccessToken(sharepointUrl.ToString(), accessToken); 
            FileInformation fInfo = SP.File.OpenBinaryDirect(clientContext, file.ServerRelativeUrl);
```

Comment: I think you're trying to return the binary (the result of the SP.File.OpenBinaryDirect() method) as a FileInformation object...

Comment: Yes but the code works in provider hosted app using high trust. This is not high trusted app. its in office 365

Answer (score 2):

Receiving a 403 (forbidden) HTTP response code when attempted to read file with OpenBinaryDirect

Solution: Use OpenBinary Instead.

See: http://tech-karma.blogspot.se/2013/05/sharepoint-2013-online-app-403-response.html

"The problem was stemming from the use of the `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect()` method.  This is a static method that is supposed to grab the file without having to call the `ExecuteQuery()` Method.  However, since I was using the oAuth App authentication model, this method apparently doesn't pass my app token along like the `ExecuteQuery()` method does."

See also http://sharxpoint.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=b8929013%2D4736%2D458f%2D81d1%2D7448cc110904&ID=16&Web=596ba2d9%2D8aa2%2D43e5%2D81ac%2Da34eeee0c3d0

for alternate method with web service API